# New to sculpting. How do you add parts and connect them by sculpting?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm  new to sculpting, and I'm trying to figure out how to add objects to the head to sculpt into the other parts of my character such as ears, neck, etc. Do you add the objects as separate parts, and how do you sculpt all the separate parts together?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to add is supposed to be a part of this object, it makes more sense to add it to this object itself in *Sculpt* mode, and not add a new object, because:

- I don't think you can sculpt several objects at the same time for the moment.
- If they are different objects it will be harder to make them look like they are one.

So for example if you want to add a neck to a head, use the *Snake Hook* brush (it allows you to easily deform the topology and add geometry):

[image]

[image]

[image]

If what you want to add is another object (like for example here a hat), you can choose to create a second object. I guess it also depends on your final purpose, you can sculpt everything within one object.

Comment: I was kind of wanting to add the body from the neck. How should I go about doing that?

Comment: you can either do it in Object mode with a boolean or do it in Sculpt mode with the Snake Hook brush